# Table should change the number of rows/columns?

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

Please see the below code, the table should change the number of rows based on input selected in the selected id option below, but only the first value of select id is read, and the number of rows are not changing based on the selection, can you please point out the mistake in my code ?

http://jsfiddle.net/uTY6n/14/

HTML:

```
  <div id="scrollingDiv">
<select id="read">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option></select>

<table id="contentTable" border="1">
    <!-- Fill table programmatically -->
</table>
 </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
  function buildTable()
 {
var myTable =document.getElementById("contentTable");
var j=document.getElementById("read").value;
var rows = [];
var cells = [];

for( var i = 0; i < j; i++ )
{
    rows[i] = myTable.insertRow(i);
    if(i%3==2)rows[i].addClass("everyrow");
    cells[i] = [];

    for( var x = 0; x < 3 ; x++ )
    {
        cells[i][x] =document.createElement((x==0)?"th":"td");
        cells[i][x].innerHTML = (x==0)?"<input>":"<input>";
        rows[rows.length - 1].appendChild(cells[i][x]);
    }
  }

   }
   buildTable();
```

CSS:

```
  #scrollingDiv
  {
  border: 1px groove black;
  height: 350px;
  width: 350px;
  background: #ffffff;
  overflow: auto;
  }

  #contentTable
  {
  height: 350px;
  width: 350px;
  }
  .every3rdrow{
  border-bottom:3px solid black;
  }
```

Comment: How are you triggering the call to `buildTable()`? If you just call it at top-level, it won't wait for the user to select something from the menu. You should call it from the `select`'s `onchange` handler.

Comment: You also need to empty the table before rebuilding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [**See this demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/uTY6n/15/)

First, you need to attach an event listener to the `<select>`:

```
document.getElemenyById('read').addEventListener('change', buildTable);
```

Then, you need to make sure the table is emptied before it's rebuilt every time `buildTable()` is called:

```
function buildTable() {
    var myTable =document.getElementById("contentTable");
    var j=document.getElementById("read").value;
    var rows = [];
    var cells = [];

    while (myTable.hasChildNodes()) {
        myTable.removeChild(myTable.lastChild);
    }

    ...
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function buildTable() {

var myTable =document.getElementById("contentTable");
myTable.innerHTML = "";
var j=document.getElementById("read").value;
var rows = [];
var cells = [];
var myHtml = "";

    for( var i = 0; i < j; i++ ) {
        myHtml += "<tr>";
             for( var x = 0; x < 3 ; x++ ){
                myHtml += "<td></td>"
             }
        myHtml += "</tr>";
    }
myTable.innerHTML = myHtml;
}
```

thats the general idea, also be sure to call this `onChange` of your select.